# An identity of 2-order complex matrice

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

## Problem statement

$A,B,C$ are 2-order complex matrices.

Prove $A(BC-CB)^2=(BC-CB)^2A$.

## What I have tried

I think the conditions 'complex' and '2-order' is to tell me that there're only two possibilities of their Jodan Cononial Forms,so I tried to write down JCF of $A$ but did not get more.I think the reason is I miss the information of the special structure of $BC-CB$.

So how to prove it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"$2$-order" means $2 \times 2$.  "Complex" is irrelevant: this actually works over any field.

Hint 1:
An $n \times n$ matrix that commutes with all $n \times n$ matrices must be a scalar multiple of the identity matrix $I$.  So if the statement is true, it is true
because $(BC-CB)^2$ is a scalar multiple of $I$.

Hint 2: $BC - CB$ has trace $0$. So what could its JCF be?